# How many different ways can I add three numbers to get a certain sum?

Tags: puzzle, combinations

I'm working on a little program and I stumbled across a small math problem I can't quite solve. This is what the program does.

A sum is generated. Now, the user can subtract either 3, 4, or 5 from this sum any number of times. The goal is to have the sum reduced to exactly 0. I want to know how many different ways that the sum can be reduced to zero, and ideally, what those number combinations are.

For example, if the Sum is 27, I could subtract 3 three times and 5 three times, or I could take 3 nine times, etc.

Furthermore, if we call a subtraction a "move", at some point the player will only have a certain number of moves, and I need to know how many ways I can drop 27 to 0 subtracting only 3, 4, or 5, using only, say, 6 moves.

I've mostly been getting around not knowing how to do this by guessing combinations of numbers, but I feel like there's an easier way.

Comment: does the order in which they are removed matter?

Comment: No, the order is unimportant.

Comment: You want to count compositions with parts of sizes 3,4 and 5

Comment: @ModdedBear Oh, thanks for naming my problem.

Comment: FWIW, this game is a form of [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order in which they are removed **does** matter, you can approach this via *generating functions*.  The number of different ways in which you can do this without restriction on number of moves will be the coefficient of the $x^n$ term in the expansion of $(1+x^3+x^4+x^5)^N$ where $N\geq \lceil n/3\rceil$.

If you want to restrict the number of moves, you can put an upper bound on $N$ and move it lower to equal the number of moves.  For example, if the number is $30$ and we want to have it done in at most 8 moves, look at the $x^n$ term in the expansion of $(1+x^3+x^4+x^5)^N$ where $N=8$.  To make it *exactly* 8 moves, then remove the $+1$ term in the generating function.

Comment: When you say "the number you are interested in", are you referring to the total number of possible moves? Also, which is the coefficient of the x^n  term?

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit elementary over here but I do appreciate the help.

Comment: This seems to give the answer when order is important

Comment: @ModdedBear yes, I think you are correct.  I made a mistake in the formula anyways, forgetting the +1.  I'm rethinking it, my apologies.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got this now. Thank you for the interest and help.

Answer (score -1):

Add 5 four times, add 4 once, add 3 once. :5+5+5+5+4+3=27 (6 moves)